# When to use which design pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I like design patterns very much, but I find it difficult to see when I can apply one. I have read a lot of websites where design patterns are explained. I do understand the most of them, but I find it difficult to recognize a pattern in my own situations.

So, that is why I ask this question. Are there any guidelines / alarm bells when to use which design pattern.

For example, if you are doing a switch statement to determine which object you need to create, you probably want to use the factory design pattern. So the switch statement in this case is a 'alarm bell' to use the Factory pattern.

So, do you know more 'alarm bells' to determine a design pattern?

Comment: Usually the pattern descriptions I see include a description of the situations where you would want to that design pattern.

Answer (score 100):

Usually the process is the other way around. Do not go looking for situations where to use design patterns, look for code that can be optimized. When you have code that you think is not structured correctly. try to find a design pattern that will solve the problem.

Design patterns are meant to help you solve structural problems, do not go design your application just to be able to use design patterns.

Comment: Not only structural problems, but behavioral and creational problems as well.

Comment: Design patterns can speed up the development process by providing tested, proven development paradigms. Effective software design requires considering issues that may not become visible until later in the implementation. Reusing design patterns helps to prevent subtle issues that can cause major problems and improves code readability for coders and architects familiar with the patterns.

Answer (score 5):

Learn them and slowly you'll be able to reconize and figure out when to use them. Start with something simple as the singleton pattern :)

if you want to create one instance of an object and just ONE. You use the singleton pattern. Let's say you're making a program with an options object. You don't want several of those, that would be silly. Singleton makes sure that there will never be more than one. Singleton pattern is simple, used a lot, and really effective.

Comment: The singleton is not really for when you *need only one* instance. Singleton is for when you need to *limit* to one instance. When you *need only one* instance, you can try simply creating only one instance and using it.

Comment: Also, while singleton is very useful and necessary in some places, it is also a very easy pattern to implement when not necessary. As you hint at here, and as Fernandes pointed out, you probably don't need it. As a matter of fact, a singleton pattern usage is a good sign of possible (probably) code smells. Using it for a service class is more than likely a code smell. Sounds like you need D.I., not singleton. Some people do use them that way. Especially for small (unimportant) code, or POC's. But like I said, there are some effective uses. Don't find an easy way to do something and just do it.

Answer (score 4):

I completely agree with @Peter Rasmussen.

Design patterns provide general solution to commonly occurring design problem.

I would like you to follow below approach.

1. Understand intent of each pattern
2. Understand checklist or use case of each pattern
3. Think of solution to your problem and check if your solution falls into checklist of particular pattern
4. If not, simply ignore the design-patterns and write your own solution.

Useful links:

[sourcemaking](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns) : Explains **intent**, **structure** and **checklist** beautifully in multiple languages including C++ and Java

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) : Explains structure, UML diagram and working examples in multiple languages including C# and Java .

***Check list*** and ***Rules of thumb*** in each [sourcemakding](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns) design-pattern provides alram bell you are looking for.