# Which design pattern should i use for a dynamic report generator?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm a newbie in Design Patterns. Even researching a lot, i was not able to understand when should i use which design pattern. My question is: Which design pattern should i use to implement a report generator like the one below, in a web application context?

=======================================================

**report type:**         | *'select list' here*  |

**report subtype:**   | *another select 'list'* |


**Filters:**                 | *Many selects, many filtering parameters* |

=======================================================

the report type and subtype lets the user to generate many kinds of reports, one different from another, however the filters are the same for all (but not all filter values will be used or valid for all the reports). I am using C#. I've looked in another questions about choosing design patterns, but with no success. Which design pattern should i use?
Thanks in advance folks :D.
(note: I've asked this question for studying purposes)

Comment: Why do you think this can be solved with a design pattern? Your using it like a buzzword without knowing what you need it for.

Comment: Are trying to write a web or desktop application?

Comment: i am studying design patterns, and trying to aply them in my real world applications. I'm not trying to solve anything, just understand.

Comment: this is for a web application

Comment: The alternative is you use existing Reporting software. e.g. If you are using SQL Server, it provides Reporting Services (SSRS). SSRS has a web control you can drop on your web forms which makes reporting from your database easy. It does however tie you into a specific solution which you may not want...

Comment: i've asked this question for studying purposes only. My goal is to understand and identify when which design pattern is suitable for which situation. I understand that design patterns may not be used like a buzzword:) So, i dont want to use SSRS, because this is not my goal, sarin :D

Comment: If you want to learn Design Patterns you need to know that each of them are for a specific problem. Not all problems can be solved with a Design Pattern but is just related to an architecture design.

Comment: See this Question on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039752/when-to-use-which-design-pattern?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with all the comments here that design patterns themselves aren't a *goal*, they are a *tool*. Your TA/prof are putting the wrong idea in your head by making it seem like a given task requires a given design pattern.

Aside from that...

Implement yourself a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Your factory will produce a list of available IReports and possibly return some metadata about them.

```
public class ReportData{
}

public class ReportResult{
}

public class ReportOptions{
}

public class ReportSubtype{
}

public interface IReport{
  string Name{get;}
  string[] ReportSubtype{get;}
  string[] ReportOptions {get;}

  ReportResult GetReport(ReportData data, ReportSubtype subtype, ReportOptions options);
}

public class ReportSample: IReport{
  //.... your implementation
}

public static class ReportFactory{  

  private IReport[] _reports = null; // cache the instances - optional

  public static IReport[] GetAvailableReports(){
    if (_reports==null)  // static definition can be replaced with dynamic loading
       _reports = new IReport[]{
                    new ReportSample(),
                  };

    return _reports;
  }
}
```

Comment: I disagree partially. It's good to "experiment" with design patterns when you're learning, because they're not trivial. See http://books.google.ca/books?id=GGpXN9SMELMC&lpg=PA597&ots=IpJ7KNN6HY&dq=design%20pattern%20zen&pg=PA597#v=onepage&q=design%20pattern%20zen&f=false On the other hand, Stackoverflow is not really a great place to ask questions about beginner experiments with design patterns.

Answer (score 6):

Design patterns aren't intended for you to pick *one* to use for an application.  Design patterns are useful tools that can help you structure the components that make up your application.  The best way is to start developing your application, and wherever you find your code is becoming awkward or hard to understand, look at what you've learned about patterns to see if there's some ideas that can help improve your code.  As you gain experience, you'll find you're using patterns naturally to avoid code problems.